# Google Maps, Load markers with DispatchQueue

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, swift3

I'm using a `dispatch` to add markers from a `ViewController` to `AnotherViewController`

I'm using:

**ViewTypeViewController**

```
class ViewTypeViewController: UIViewController {

    var places = [PlaceModel]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            print("Run on background thread!!!")
            self.places.append(PlaceModel(_id: 0, _name: "Park", _lat: 34.1331168, _lng: -118.3550723, _icon: "i01" ) )
            self.places.append(PlaceModel(_id: 1, _name: "Library", _lat: 34.1251168, _lng: -118.3590723, _icon: "i02"))
            let mapVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MapVC") as! MapViewController
            mapVC.places = self.places
            mapVC.callerLoaded = true
            mapVC.load()
        })        
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

**MapViewController**

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var containerDetail: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var placeName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var logo: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var stars: HCSStarRatingView!

    var places = [PlaceModel]()
    var markerDict: [Int: GMSMarker] = [:]
    var selected: Int = 0

    var callerLoaded: Bool = false
    var mapLoaded: Bool = false

    var zoom: Float = 15

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mapView.delegate = self

        containerDetail.isHidden = true
        containerDetail.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        containerDetail.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor

        logo.setRounded()

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 34.1381168, longitude: -118.3555723, zoom: zoom)
        self.mapView.camera = camera

        do {
            if let styleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "style", withExtension: "json") {
                mapView.mapStyle = try GMSMapStyle(contentsOfFileURL: styleURL)
            } else {
                NSLog("Unable to find style.json")
            }
        } catch {
            NSLog("One or more of the map styles failed to load. \(error)")
        }

    }


    func load(){

        var index: Int = 0

        for place in places {
            let marker = GMSMarker()
            marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: place.lat, longitude: place.lng)
            marker.title = place.name
            marker.snippet = place.name
            marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop
            marker.map = self.mapView
            markerDict[place.id] = marker
            index = index + 1
        }
    }

}
```

The method `load` in the `MapViewController` is loaded ok, but, any `marker` is added to my `map`.

I'm not getting any errors there.

Some idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just seems like a timing issue, where you setup your controller here...

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        // actually running on the main thread async
        self.places.append(PlaceModel(_id: 0, _name: "Park", _lat: 34.1331168, _lng: -118.3550723, _icon: "i01" ) )
        self.places.append(PlaceModel(_id: 1, _name: "Library", _lat: 34.1251168, _lng: -118.3590723, _icon: "i02"))
        let mapVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MapVC") as! MapViewController
        mapVC.places = self.places
        mapVC.callerLoaded = true
        mapVC.load()
    })
```

Initilising the view controller with the array of places is fine, but when you call `mapVC.load()` you are calling it before the view has loaded. Your map is only initialized properly in `viewDidLoad`. So you are trying to add the markers before the map is fully ready and the view actually loaded.

remove `mapVC.load()`

and at the end of `viewDidLoad()` in MapViewController add `self.load()` and see how that works.